# Outsourced rocket engines for medium and small launchers

Tags: engines

Is there any company selling rocket engines that work for small and medium orbital launchers other than Ursa Major Technologies?

Looks like a good model: the company developing a rocket can save a lot of time and money not having to spend for devoping their own engines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major example is [NPO Energomash](http://engine.space/eng/), developing and selling engines to several Russian an American launch vehicles.

As an example of small launcher, the company delivered the first stage engine of the Korean [Naro-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naro-1) rocket.

As a larger example, it delivers the RD-180 which powers the first stage of the [Atlas V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_V).

Saving time and money was the deciding factor for Orbital Sciences Corporation to buy NK-33 an later RD-181 engines for the [Antares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antares_(rocket)) from NPO Energomash, rather than developing a new high-performance kerolox engine.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found:

- [Protolaunch](https://www.protolaunch.co.uk/) (UK)
- [Reach Space Technologies](https://reachspace.com/)
- [Jiuzhou Yunjian](https://twitter.com/aj_fi/status/1127850626602369025?lang=en) [(China)](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/QqUCCembPeJydjA-bNmTDg)
- Aerojet Rocketdyne has completed the assembly of the first AR1 - kerolox engine